# Difference between this two codes(Why is my array taking extra space even if i gave a limit to it)

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I declared an array of size 10 in two ways( one is by assigning directly and the other is assigning the value to a variable(here, it is the size) and passing it to the array. Problem is for the first case, there was a restriction to the array size when I crossed the limit but in the second case the array size got exceeded and but still I'm not getting an error) can I know what is happening?? thanks in advance! :)

PS: When I saw the address everything was in an order fashion.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

//global declaration
int top =-1;

void push(int array[],int value){
 top = top+1;
 array[top] = value;
 cout<<"Pushed "<<value<<" at "<< top << " position"<< endl;

}

void pop(){
    top = top -1;
}


void Gettop(int size){
    cout<< "top is at "<< top << " of "<<size<<endl;
}

bool isEmpty(){
    if(top == -1){
        return true;
    }
}

int GetTopval(int array[]){
    return array[top];
}



int main(){
   int size=10;

   int oldArray[size];

   push(oldArray,2);
   push(oldArray,23);
   push(oldArray,22);
   push(oldArray,24);
   push(oldArray,242);
   push(oldArray,22);
   push(oldArray,21);
      push(oldArray,2);
   push(oldArray,23);
   push(oldArray,22);
   push(oldArray,24);
   push(oldArray,242);
   push(oldArray,22);
   push(oldArray,21);
     push(oldArray,242);
   push(oldArray,22);
   push(oldArray,21);
   pop();
   push(oldArray,211);
   int value = GetTopval(oldArray);

   cout<< "VAlue : "<< value<<endl;

cout<< "printing the Array: "<<endl;
for(int i=0;i<15;i++){
    int *temp = &oldArray[i];
    cout<<oldArray[i]<<" with i as "<< i <<endl;
    cout<<"at address : "<< temp <<endl;
}


    return 0;
}
```

Another case is:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

//global declaration
int top =-1;

void push(int array[],int value){
 top = top+1;
 array[top] = value;
 cout<<"Pushed "<<value<<" at "<< top << " position"<< endl;

}

void pop(){
    top = top -1;
}


void Gettop(int size){
    cout<< "top is at "<< top << " of "<<size<<endl;
}

bool isEmpty(){
    if(top == -1){
        return true;
    }
}

int GetTopval(int array[]){
    return array[top];
}



int main(){
   int size=10;

   int oldArray[size];

   push(oldArray,2);
   push(oldArray,23);
   push(oldArray,22);
   push(oldArray,24);
   push(oldArray,242);
   push(oldArray,22);
   push(oldArray,21);
      push(oldArray,2);
   push(oldArray,23);
   push(oldArray,22);
   push(oldArray,24);
   push(oldArray,242);
   push(oldArray,22);
   push(oldArray,21);
     push(oldArray,242);
   push(oldArray,22);
   push(oldArray,21);
   pop();
   push(oldArray,211);
   int value = GetTopval(oldArray);

   cout<< "VAlue : "<< value<<endl;

cout<< "printing the Array: "<<endl;
for(int i=0;i<15;i++){
    int *temp = &oldArray[i];
    cout<<oldArray[i]<<" with i as "<< i <<endl;
    cout<<"at address : "<< temp <<endl;
}


    return 0;
}
```

Output for case2:

```
Pushed 2 at 0 position
Pushed 23 at 1 position
Pushed 22 at 2 position
Pushed 24 at 3 position
Pushed 242 at 4 position
Pushed 22 at 5 position
Pushed 21 at 6 position
Pushed 2 at 7 position
Pushed 23 at 8 position
Pushed 22 at 9 position
Pushed 24 at 10 position
Pushed 242 at 11 position
Pushed 22 at 12 position
Pushed 21 at 13 position
Pushed 242 at 14 position
Pushed 22 at 15 position
Pushed 21 at 16 position
Pushed 211 at 16 position
VAlue : 211
printing the Array: 
2 with i as 0
at address : 0x7ffffbb707c0
23 with i as 1
at address : 0x7ffffbb707c4
22 with i as 2
at address : 0x7ffffbb707c8
24 with i as 3
at address : 0x7ffffbb707cc
242 with i as 4
at address : 0x7ffffbb707d0
22 with i as 5
at address : 0x7ffffbb707d4
21 with i as 6
at address : 0x7ffffbb707d8
2 with i as 7
at address : 0x7ffffbb707dc
23 with i as 8
at address : 0x7ffffbb707e0
22 with i as 9
at address : 0x7ffffbb707e4
24 with i as 10
at address : 0x7ffffbb707e8
242 with i as 11
at address : 0x7ffffbb707ec
22 with i as 12
at address : 0x7ffffbb707f0
13 with i as 13
at address : 0x7ffffbb707f4
242 with i as 14
at address : 0x7ffffbb707f8
```

Output for case1:

```
Pushed 2 at 0 position
Pushed 23 at 1 position
Pushed 22 at 2 position
Pushed 24 at 3 position
Pushed 242 at 4 position
Pushed 22 at 5 position
Pushed 21 at 6 position
Pushed 2 at 7 position
Pushed 23 at 8 position
Pushed 22 at 9 position
Pushed 24 at 10 position
Pushed 242 at 11 position
Pushed 22 at 12 position
Pushed 21 at 13 position
Pushed 242 at 14 position
Pushed 22 at 15 position
Pushed 21 at 16 position
Pushed 211 at 16 position
VAlue : 211
printing the Array: 
2 with i as 0
at address : 0x7fff8be0b780
23 with i as 1
at address : 0x7fff8be0b784
22 with i as 2
at address : 0x7fff8be0b788
24 with i as 3
at address : 0x7fff8be0b78c
242 with i as 4
at address : 0x7fff8be0b790
22 with i as 5
at address : 0x7fff8be0b794
21 with i as 6
at address : 0x7fff8be0b798
2 with i as 7
at address : 0x7fff8be0b79c
23 with i as 8
at address : 0x7fff8be0b7a0
22 with i as 9
at address : 0x7fff8be0b7a4
24 with i as 10
at address : 0x7fff8be0b7a8
242 with i as 11
at address : 0x7fff8be0b7ac
22 with i as 12
at address : 0x7fff8be0b7b0
21 with i as 13
at address : 0x7fff8be0b7b4
242 with i as 14
at address : 0x7fff8be0b7b8
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: To begin with, your code is not valid C++ code because C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). Secondly you have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because you will go out of bounds of the arrays.

Comment: VLAs are not *standard* C++ code. Whether C++ with extensions is a *valid* or not, that's more of a judgement call, because "valid" can be defined in many ways. Still, VLAs should be avoided even in C, unless there is a compelling reason to use them (because stack overflow is nasty).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "extra space". You have an array of size `10` but you access it out-of-bounds and by this invoke undefined behaviour.

After calling this more than 10 times:

```
void push(int array[],int value){
 top = top+1;
 array[top] = value;
 cout<<"Pushed "<<value<<" at "<< top << " position"<< endl;

}
```

you will access `array[10]` which is already out-of-bounds.

In a nutshell, undefined behaviour means: the compiler is not required to warn you or produce an error, your code may appear to work, but when running it anything can happen. The c++ standard does not define what happens when you break the rules.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer.. so that I can have more clarity! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @teachMe i tried to be as clear as I can. If something is unclear or needs further explanation you have to tell me what

Comment: Undefined behaviour does not mean the compiler "must not warn you".   It means (among other things) that the compiler is not required to give a warning.  The two statements are not equivalent.    There are plenty of compilers (with appropriate settings) that issue warnings about particular coding constructs that exhibit - or have potential to exhibit - undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Peter oh thats due to my bad english not due to misunderstanding of ub, fixed